# Unsafe threading with dictionary - Let's break some stuff

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, dictionary

So at the bottom of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx we see

> A Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue) can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified. Even so, enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. In the rare case where an enumeration contends with write accesses, the collection must be locked during the entire enumeration. To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization.

In my asp.net application, I occasionally see NullReferenceExceptions generated from inside System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert.

How could I recreate this in a sandbox?

The following code doesn't cause the exception, in spite of a local dictionary being accessed by separate threads.

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        int maxThreads = 20;
        Dictionary<Guid, Guid> dict = new Dictionary<Guid, Guid>();
        var tws = new threadWithState();
        while (true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < maxThreads * 2; i++) {
                var thread = new Thread(tws.Work);
                thread.IsBackground = true;
                thread.Start(dict);
            }
            dict[Guid.NewGuid()] = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
    }
}

class threadWithState {
    public void Work(object dict) {
        Console.WriteLine((dict as Dictionary<Guid, Guid>).Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            (dict as Dictionary<Guid, Guid>)[Guid.NewGuid()] = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code suffers from accidental synchronization due to the garbage collected heap lock.  You'll get it to crash much quicker by injecting random delays, much like what happens on the actual server.  This code made it crash in a fraction of a second on my machine, ymmv:

```
        public void Work(object dict) {
            var rnd = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine((dict as Dictionary<Guid, Guid>).Count);
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
                (dict as Dictionary<Guid, Guid>)[Guid.NewGuid()] = Guid.NewGuid();
                for (int ix = 0; ix < rnd.Next(1000); ++ix) ;   // NOTE: random delay
            }
        }
```

Comment: This makes sense, but it's generating a different exception.  IndexOutOfBounds instead of NullReferenceException.

Comment: Yes, there is certainly more than one way you'll break the class by not using locks.  Note that you're not simulating reads, more likely to generate NRE.  One failure mode is enough, I'd say.

Answer (score 8):

That's part of the problem with threading - bugs are not necessarily reproducible reliably.  The issue is that the insert has to hit a specific race condition, which obviously isn't happening in your test.  Of course, enough runs may cause this to trigger, but that's going to be difficult to reliably test.

That being said, this is obviously a problem.  Instead of focusing on reproducing it, you should consider how to just correct it.  The obvious answer here, of course, is to switch to a different technique, such as using a `ConcurrentDictionary<T,U>` instead, which is thread safe.

Comment: Oh, I agree about simply correcting it.  I'd like to be able to show that ConcurrentDictionary<T,U> is the correct fix.

So the workflow is something like, recreate the broken state, change to ConcurrentDictionary and show it not breaking.

What can I do to increase the chances that the target machine instruction is getting called?  Should I spawn eleventy-billion threads?  Should I do something like pausing threads before their inserts then somehow signaling them to open the insert floodgates and cross my fingers?  How would that be done?

Comment: @MushinNoShin You probably need to increase the size of your loop in the threads dramatically.  More threads isn't the problem - they're not running long enough, though.  Try inserting (and removing?) a million, or 10 million items instead one thousand...